# Ignore unit tests part of an ordered test

Tags: visual-studio, automated-tests, integration-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

I've got a VS2015 Update 2 solution which includes a Unit Test project. As part of the test project, I've got a bunch of unit tests and some integration tests.

The integration tests are ordered tests which fire off a bunch of test method in the correct sequence, along with some initialization code which injects some actual dependencies instead of just mocks.

When I now run my tests from VS, it's hitting the unit tests which are in the ordered tests twice. I guess once because they're in the ordered tests file, and once because the methods are labeled [TestMethod] (but otherwise I can't add them to the ordered test file). This is not what I intended; I need these methods to run only as part of the ordered test, they should not fire off individually (in the wrong sequence).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to go with one TestMethod that calls several methods for the integration scenario. This eliminates the need to 'hide' the tests which are part of the ordered test, in fact it eliminates the entire need for the ordered test. Word of caution: you should **not** be calling other tests from within your test, simply create a seperate class which sets up the integration test scenario and runs all of the tests you want to perform.